# How can I create multiple Datasets with different class types from one general Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `Dataset[General]` which I would like to split into two Datasets. One Dataset[Mary] and one Dataset[John]. I would like to have as many rows based the amount of structures that exist in the add_marry or add_john arrays. I want to use Datasets and therefore not use the Dataframe API which would allow me to explode. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated! The input is

```
List(General("1","Bob",[{"1","2"},{"1","3"}],[{"11","12"},{"21","23"}])).toDS
```

And output would be

```
Dataset[John] = (("1","Bob","11","12"),("1","Bob","21","12"))
Dataset[Mary] = (("1","Bob","1","2"),("1","Bob","1","3"))
```

Classes =

```
case class General (
 id: String,
 name: String,
 add_marry: Array[AddressMary],
 add_john: Array[AddressJohn]
)

case class AddressMary (
 streetUK: String,
 houseUK: String
)

case class AddressJohn (
streetUS: String,
houseUS: String
)

case class John (
 id: String,
 name: String,
 street: String,
 house: String)

case class Mary (
 id: String,
 name: String,
 street: String,
 house: String)
```

I have tried to do a for loop but this doesnt seem to work as I am not getting a row for each address that they have.

```
val dsHome = dfHome.as[General]
      .flatMap(pf => {
if (pf.add_marry.size > 0) for (e <- pf) {
        Mary(pf.id,pf.name,e.streetUK, e.houseUK)
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you were trying to do:

```scala
val dfHome: DataFrame = ???
val dsHome: Dataset[General] = dfHome.as[General]

val dsMary1: Dataset[Mary] = dsHome.flatMap { case General(id, name, addrs, _) =>
  addrs.map { case AddressMary(street, house) => Mary(id, name, street, house) }
}
val dsJohn1: Dataset[John] = dsHome.flatMap { case General(id, name, _, addrs) =>
  addrs.map { case AddressJohn(street, house) => John(id, name, street, house) }
}
```

You can also rewrite it with for-comprehension as:

```scala
val dsMary2: Dataset[Mary] =
  for {
    General(id, name, addrs, _) <- dsHome
    AddressMary(street, house) <- addrs
  } yield Mary(id, name, street, house)

val dsJohn2: Dataset[John] =
  for {
    General(id, name, _, addrs) <- dsHome
    AddressJohn(street, house) <- addrs
  } yield John(id, name, street, house)
```

but you will need the plugin [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) as [`withFilter` isn't implemented for `Dataset`](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for#destructuring-either--io--task--flatmap).

EDIT: Author asked for a way to get the `Dataset` of `John` and `Mary` at one go. We could `zip` the inner arrays but this would require every element one array to have a corresponding element in the other array in the same order. We could also nest the flatMaps together but that would be equivalent to a cartesian join.

```scala
val dsMaryJohnZip1: Dataset[(Mary, John)] = dsHome.flatMap { case General(id, name, addrMs, addrJs) =>
  addrMs.zip(addrJs).map { case (AddressMary(sM, hM), AddressJohn(sJ, hJ)) => (Mary(id, name, sM, hM), John(id, name, sJ, hJ)) }
}
val dsMaryJohnZip2: Dataset[(Mary, John)] =
  for {
    General(id, name, addrMs, addrJs) <- dsHome
    (AddressMary(sM, hM), AddressJohn(sJ, hJ)) <- addrMs.zip(addrJs)
  } yield (Mary(id, name, sM, hM), John(id, name, sJ, hJ))

val dsMaryJohnCartesian1: Dataset[(Mary, John)] = dsHome.flatMap { case General(id, name, addrMs, addrJs) =>
  addrMs.flatMap { case AddressMary(sM, hM) =>
    addrJs.map { case AddressJohn(sJ, hJ) =>
      (Mary(id, name, sM, hM), John(id, name, sJ, hJ))
    }
  }
}
val dsMaryJohnCatesian2: Dataset[(Mary, John)] =
  for {
    General(id, name, addrMs, addrJs) <- dsHome
    AddressMary(sM, hM) <- addrMs
    AddressJohn(sJ, hJ) <- addrJs
  } yield (Mary(id, name, sM, hM), John(id, name, sJ, hJ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was hoping to use only 1 flatmap because in reality I am creating 4 different datasets instead of 2 and felt like writing the same code 4 times was ugly. Would you think it is also possible with 1 flatmap? And returning a tuple with 4 different Datasets

Comment: @HenriThorpe No because you can't nest datasets in Spark. By forming a tuple it you would get `Dataset[(Array[Mary], Array[John])]`, which means you will still need similar repetitive flatMaps to get back `Dataset[Mary]` and `Dataset[John]`. You could zip `Array[Mary]` and `Array[John]` and you will get Dataset[(Mary, John)] but I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @HenriThorpe You can also write polymorphic functions to reduce duplication but will probably need some type level programming with some thing like Shapeless which is probably an overkill for what you are doing, This is why most Spark devs fallback to untyped `DataFrame`.

Comment: @HenriThorpe you can also nest the flatMaps for John and Mary to get `DataFrame[(Mary, John)]` but this will be a cartesian product.

Comment: @HenriThorpe I've provided the zip and cartesian versions for producing the tuples.